# How can i run ksonnet command on kubernetes cluster from inside a container on the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, ksonnet

I am trying to trigger ksonnet component deployment from within a container on a kubernetes cluster. The ks component prototype is on the node itself. I am just trying to execute ks generate and ks apply command on the node from inside a container on the node.

Answer (score 0):

A container, or a pod do not have access to node resources. They are isolated. You have to run a pod with ksonnet, within the cluster, with `kubectl run ...`

Comment: Can we do this by creating or, using existing apis? If there is any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

ksonnet uses Kubernetes' client-go to determine cluster credentials. If this is not working properly, could you please create an issue in [ksonnet issues](http://github.com/ksonnet/ksonnet/issues)